# Add extra config folder to classpath using maven

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I want to build a standalone application which has the following directory structure:

```
./launch.bat
./config/application.properties
./lib/application.jar
./lib/dependancy1.jar
./lib/dependancy2.jar
```

The manifest file of `application.jar` contains a Class-Path entry listing all dependant jars. The `application.properties` file is loaded as a resource so I would like to add the `./config` folder to my classpath.

In `launch.bat` the application is launched using :

```
 java -jar ./lib/application.jar
```

By using the `-jar` option the classpath system variable or -classpath parameter are ignored :(. The classpath must be set completely within the manifest.mf of the application.jar. So my Class-Path should become something like:

```
 Class-Path:../config dependancy1.jar dependancy2.jar
```

How can I do this using maven ?
My current maven jar plugin :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>org.conffusion.myapp.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is this a Spring Boot application?

Comment: no. plain old java

Comment: If you like to have the given structure you should take a look into the maven-assembly-plugin otherwise you won't get that via maven-jar-plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the metainf part is delegated to the maven-archiver and these configuration parameters look very similar to maven-jar-plugin so without the option I need. I mainly liked the -jar option so I don't need to specify the dependencies on the command line but found out it is allowed to put wildcards in the -cp parameter so changed my command to `java  -cp lib\*;config\ org.conffusion.myapp.Main`. Thanks for the effort

Comment: But you need to use maven-assembly-plugin (which also supports maven-archiver configuration) to create an archive as you like to have ...with maven-jar-plugin you are not able to create such a structure within the jar..

Comment: @khmarbaise. I didn't find how to configure this in the assembly.xml. Can you provide an answer with an example of the configuration elements to use?

Comment: The configuration for the archive like class path etc. is in the plugin not in the assembly descriptor...as in the maven-jar-plugin...